# Rendering a large QGraphicsScene on a QImage clips it off

Tags: qt, rendering, qgraphicsscene, qpainter

I am creating some images rendering the contents of a `QGraphicsScene`.
My project requirement is that it should handle a canvas size of 10 ft by 8 inches. On screen, and scene size, that is 8640 x 576 pixels.
I can render it fine.

The thing is, the output images need to have 300 resolution.
That means, the rendered image will have a width of 36000, which is over `2^15 - 1 = 32767` pixels.....

The output is clipped - in the code below, I would get a `QImage` of correct expected size (36000) but the `QGraphicsScene` only renders to 32767 pixels.

That is confusing... I cannot explain the outcome - if the `QImage` limitations were 32767 pixels, then I should not be able to create one in the first place.  But I checked and the `QImage` "sanity check" is much higher.

Once the image is created, I do not see anything in the code for rendering `QGraphicsScene` that would clip at any value....

This is a simple code that is trying to expose my problem.
It creates a `QImage` of required size, and fills with yellow (for control).
Then it renders a `QGraphicsScene` with blue background brush and a red rectangle close to the right margin.
If it works correctly, the result should be: an image of width 36000, blue with a tiny red rectangle at the far right.
But... as it is, the result is an image of width 36000, blue for the first 32766 pixels then yellow for the rest, no red rectangle.

[image]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>

void printScene(QGraphicsScene* s, qreal ratio) {
    qreal w = s->width() * ratio;
    qreal h = s->height() * ratio;
    QRectF target(0, 0, w, h);
    QImage image = QImage(w, h, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    image.fill(QColor(Qt::yellow).rgb());

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&image);
    s->render(&painter, target);
    painter.end();
    image.save("image.png");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene s;
    s.setSceneRect(0, 0, 8640, 576);
    s.setBackgroundBrush(Qt::blue);
    QGraphicsView view(&s);
    view.show();
    QGraphicsRectItem* r = s.addRect(8530, 250, 100, 100);
    r->setBrush(Qt::red);
    qreal ratio = 300/72.;
    printScene(&s, ratio);
    return app.exec();
}
```

As seen in sample images, the `QImage` is created successfully, `QGraphicsScene` though only renders to `2^15 - 1`... But I stepped through their code and I didn't see it stop....

(I also tried creating the original scene 36000 x something (and setting the `ratio` to 1), and it displays fine... it just won't render to `QImage` anything beyond 32767 pixels)

Am I missing some setting ? What could be the cause of the `QGraphicsScene::render()` to not render more ?

I would love to find out how I can render the size I want - width of 36000 pixels - or a reason why this is not possible.

I am running this in Windows 7, 32 bit Qt 5.5.1 or 4.7.4

Comment: I've run your code and it creates the correct image 36000x2400  QtCreator 3.4.1/ MSVC 2013 32bit Qt 5.4.2 Windows 7 Pro

[link](http://wdfiles.ru/11jv)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin As you can see, the image does not match the contents of the scene, it is clipped off. Your attachment shows exactly what is happening - you get the blue scene up to 32767 pixels, which is too short to display the red rectangle, and the rest of the image is prefilled with yellow. The image is created - filled - but the scene only partially rendered. (I had screenshots posted in the history of this, but they didn't seem helpful so I had them removed, you can still look)

Comment: I updated to add prettier images for "expected" and "actual" and describe the problem so it is easier to understand without reading/running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for the clipping - and imagined 2 workarounds.

**Why:**

Stepping through the rendering code, the clip rect gets limited to 32767:

```
bool QRasterPaintEngine::setClipRectInDeviceCoords(const QRect &r, Qt::ClipOperation op)
{
    Q_D(QRasterPaintEngine);
    QRect clipRect = r & d->deviceRect;
    ...
}
```

Where `deviceRect` is set by

```
void QRasterPaintEnginePrivate::systemStateChanged()
{
    deviceRectUnclipped = QRect(0, 0,
            qMin(QT_RASTER_COORD_LIMIT, device->width()),
            qMin(QT_RASTER_COORD_LIMIT, device->height()));

    QRegion clippedDeviceRgn = systemClip & deviceRectUnclipped;
    deviceRect = clippedDeviceRgn.boundingRect();
    baseClip->setClipRegion(clippedDeviceRgn);
    ...
}
```

and

```
// This limitations comes from qgrayraster.c. Any higher and
// rasterization of shapes will produce incorrect results.
const int QT_RASTER_COORD_LIMIT = 32767;
```

**Options:**

1) Render to a max of 32767 and, if the target must be bigger, scale result. (should give slightly lower quality)

2) Create 2 images and combine them (I still need to figure that out but I think it is the better fix)